# Remove characters and numbers from a string in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to rename a bunch of files in my directory and I'm stuck at the regex part of it.

I want to remove certain characters from a filename which appear at the beginning.

Example1: `_00-author--book_revision_`

Expected: `Author - Book (Revision)`

So far, I am able to use regex to remove underscores & captialize the first letter

```
$newfile =~ s/_/ /g;
$newfile =~ s/^[0-9]//g;
$newfile =~ s/^[0-9]//g;
$newfile =~ s/^-//g;
$newfile = ucfirst($newfile);
```

This is not a good method. I need help in removing all characters until you hit the first letter, and when you hit the first '-' I want to add a space before and after '-'.
Also when I hit the second '-' I want to replace it with '('.

Any guidance, tips or even suggestions on taking the right approach is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So do you want to capitalize all the components of the new filename, or just the first one?  Your question is inconsistent on that point.

Note that if you are on Linux, you probably have the `rename` command, which will take a perl expression and use it to rename files for you, something like this:

```
rename 'my ($a,$b,$r);$_ = "$a - $b ($r)" 
  if ($a, $b, $r) = map { ucfirst $_ } /^_\d+-(.*?)--(.*?)_(.*?)_$/' _*
```

Answer (score 1):

Your instructions and your example don't match.

According to your instructions,

```
s/^[^\pL]+//;    # Remove everything until first letter.
s/-/ - /;        # Replace first "-" with " - "
s/-[^-]*\K-/(/;  # Replace second "-" with "("
```

According to your example,

```
s/^[^\pL]+//;
s/--/ - /;
s/_/ (/;
s/_/)/;
s/(?<!\pL)(\pL)/\U$1/g;
```

Comment: Thanks much!! s/-/ - /;     <- Wont this replace every '-' with ' - ' ?? Also, how can i add an ')' at the end of the file name?

Comment: I just realised my mistake. I have some files named as shown in the above example and some files named as 00-author-book-revision. In either case, i want the files to be renamed as Author - Book (revision) . But your input definitely has helped me here and I'm going to figure out how to fix the problem.

Comment: @Naveen, Without /g, it'll just replace the first. `$s .= ')';`

Answer (score 1):

```perl
$filename =~ s,^_\d+-(.*?)--(.*?)_(.*?)_$,\u\1 - \u\2 (\u\3),;
```

My Perl interpreter (using strict and warnings) says that this is better written as:

```perl
$filename =~ s,^_\d+-(.*?)--(.*?)_(.*?)_$,\u$1 - \u$2 (\u$3),;
```

The first one probably is more *sedish* for its taste! (Of course both version works just the same.)

Explanation (as requested by [stema](https://stackoverflow.com/users/626273/stema)):

```perl
$filename =~ s/
  ^       # matches the start of the line
  _\d+-   # matches an underscore, one or more digits and a hypen minus
  (.*?)-- # matches (non-greedyly) anything before two consecutive hypen-minus
          #   and captures the entire match (as the first capture group)
  (.*?)_  # matches (non-greedyly) anything before a single underscore and
          #  captures the entire match (as the second capture group)
  (.*?)_  # does the same as the one before (but captures the match as the
          #  third capture group obviously)
  $       # matches the end of the line
/\u$1 - \u$2 (\u$3)/x;
```

The `\u${1..3}` in replacement specification simply tells Perl to insert the capture groups from 1 to 3 with their first character made upper-case. If you'd wanted to make the entire match (in a captured group) upper-case you'd had to use `\U` instead.

The *x* flags turns on *verbose* mode, which tells the Perl interpreter that we want to use *#* comments, so it will ignore these (and any white space in the regular expression - so if you want to match a *space* you have to use either `\s` or `\`). Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to tell Perl to ignore white space in the * replacement* specification - this is why I've written that on a single line.

(Also note that I've changed my `s` terminator from `,` to `/` - Perl barked at me if I used the `,` with verbose mode turned on ... not exactly sure why.)

Comment: +1 for teaching me `\u`, but to make it a real good answer, please explain a bit what happens here.

Answer (score 0):

If they all follow that format then try:

```
my ($author, $book, $revision) = $newfiles =~ /-(.*?)--(.*?)_(.*?)_/;

print ucfirst($author ) . " - $book ($revision)\n";
```